# Raspberry Pi with OWFS, 8 DS18B20 sensors with DS2482-800 board, running really slow

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am working with a DS2482-800 chip and 64 DS18B20 temperature sensors on a Raspberry Pi 3 with OWFS installed. I know that each sensor should refresh every 750ms. I have been on other forums and the simple code I have, as far as I know, should be able to run fairly quickly when compared to how it is running right now. I removed all but 8 of the sensors which is attached to OW0 on the DS2482. With what I have learned this should be able to loop though within 7-10 seconds, yet it is taking 30 - 40 seconds. I have tried multithreading and tried getting OWFS to run in parallel instead of sequentially yet have struggled with it. Any help would be really appreciated.

### Result: 33.83175621025 20.9375 20.7575 20.8125 20.625 20.3755 20.6875 20.687521

```
import os
import time
while ( True ): 
    T1 = time.time()
    tempfile1 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.36624D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext1 = tempfile1.read()
    tempfile1.close()
    #print(thetext1)

    tempfile2 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.CD624D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext2 = tempfile2.read()
    tempfile2.close()
    #print(thetext2)

    tempfile3 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.BC564D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext3 = tempfile3.read()
    tempfile3.close()
    #print(thetext3)

    tempfile4 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.46594D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext4 = tempfile4.read()
    tempfile4.close()
    #print(thetext4)

    tempfile5 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.FA654D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext5 = tempfile5.read()
    tempfile5.close()
    #print(thetext5)

    tempfile6 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.613F4D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext6 = tempfile6.read()
    tempfile6.close()
    #print(thetext6)

    tempfile7 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.613F4D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext7 = tempfile7.read()
    tempfile7.close()
    #print(thetext7)

    tempfile8 = open("/mnt/1wire/28.9E534D0A0000/temperature")
    thetext8 = tempfile8.read()
    tempfile8.close()


    T0 = time.time()

    deltatime = T0 - T1

    print deltatime, thetext1, thetext2, thetext3, thetext4, thetext5, 
    print thetext6,thetext7, thetext8
    print "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: how big are these txt files? Have you tried reading them one at a time to see if there is a bottle neck?

Comment: not an answer, but your SD card's speed may affect your code's performance

Comment: its not a text file just temperature sensors, and trying to read them one at a time has the same result.

Comment: each temperature sensor data are actually written to a file. The paths in those open() functions are the paths of those files. Try copying one of these path to your file manager, you will find these files and you can view them by opening them with a text editor.

Comment: Is there another way to get the temperature values other than opening and reading the file, like having a shell command in the script? possibly a dumb question.